# How to declare timer while avoid global variables?

Tags: javascript, timer, socket.io

This is for frontend Javascript linked to an HTML file if that's relevant. I tried using IIFE for this problem and a bunch of things broke, so I'd like to avoid trying again if possible. I declared a timer that I want to stop conditionally (i.e. backend sends front end a message to stop or timer ticks for thirty seconds, whichever comes first), but I'm not sure how to do this without globally declaring a timer variable.

Here's some dummy code because the actual thing is around 300 lines:

```
const startTimer = ()=>{
  let time = 30
  const timer = setInterval(()=>{
    if(time === 0){
        clearInterval(timer)
     }
   }
  },1000)
}
startTimer()

socket.on('stop-timer', ()=>{
  //I want to clear the timer when this gets emitted.
})
```

How would I avoid declaring a global timer? Is it really that bad to do so?

Comment: The IIFE is exactly the right thing to do, what sort of problems were you having with it? (can you post that code so we can see?)

Comment: My bad, I forgot to nest some global consts inside the IIFE and that broke things. It works now...

Comment: @Stoodent You might want to just delete your question in that case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a simple class (I assume you use ES6 by the look of your code) that will expose cancel method to `clearInterval` like this:

```
class Timer {
  constructor(time) {
    this.time = time;
    this._interval = null;
  }

  start() {
    this._interval = setInterval(...);
  }

  cancel() {
    clearInterval(this._interval);
    this._interval = null;
  }
}

const timer = new Timer(30);
timer.start();

socket.on('stop-timer', timer.cancel);
```